# Using SQL to add extra data to table

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I am currently attempting to use Microsoft Access 2013 in order to create a company database, I have gotten a lot of things up and running on it for ex. Log in system, Splash Screen on start up, tables, forms, reports, a couple queries...

Although I really need to add a section for me to Add extra customers to the list while keeping the ease of use of the system see, I have a form setup for it - I have the rows of information going down. (`Customer_ID, First_Name, Surname, Street_Address, Town, Post_Code, Phone_Number, Mobile_phone_Number & Email_Address`) Made these using `text boxes`, named mytextboxes each something different referring to the base name for simpleness on my side.

The problem is - I need to `use SQL and NOT Visual Basic` in order to create a working system so I can type in data to those systems click on a button that says ADD on it then it adds the data to my table and whole system (reports etc.) and that is it, maybe a way to clear everything I have written in the text boxes above by a click of a "Clear" button as well would be great.

If anyone at all can help me with this I would be extremely grateful, I need help with this ASAP.

Comment: I don't get what exactly you do need. If you bind the form with a table or query, the records would be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Access uses VBA and not VB.  VBA is similar to SQL in that most commands are syntactically similar.

If you link the tables to your Access front end using ODBC, there is no need to write SQL/VBA code to update your tables.  However, if you really need to keep the data unbound, you can either link the tables "on the fly", or send the information to a SQL stored procedure via something along these lines:

```
    Dim cnComments As New ADODB.Connection
    'Set up the connection string
    strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=MySQLServername;INITIAL CATALOG=MySQLDBName;"
    cnComments.Open strConn

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    UName = "My Username"
    TName = "My DB"
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = strConn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "sp_MyStoredProcedureName"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@FNLNUserName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, UName)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@GetCurrDBName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 150, TName)
        .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
    End With
```

Unfortunately, without more info, that's about the best I can do.

EDIT: After re-reading your post, I think the best solution is to link the SQL tables to Access using ODBC, and then use an "Unbound" form in Access.  This will allow you to place "Save" and "Clear" buttons on the form, and only save the data when "Save" is clicked.  Behind the "Save" button, you can either use an Append query or write SQL/VBA to write the values of your textboxes to the table.  Or, again, as above you can send the values of those textboxes to a SQL stored procedure and have SQL do the updating.